# How to get the first string's from the right hand side

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have this code that would get the first string's from the right hand side and stop whenever there is an integer but for some reason its not working with me.

Example input of fUnit is "CS_25x2u"

expected output of it after using unit is "u".

Real output is "undefined".

```
function buildUnit(fUnit){// wahts ginna be passed here is the gibirish unit and the output of this function is the clear unit
    fUnit = fUnit.toString;
    const regex = /[a-zA-Z]*$/;
    const unit = (x) => x.match(regex)[0];
    fUnit = unit(fUnit);
```

If you need more info please let me know

Thank you

Comment: I think that in your script if you want to use `toString`, `toString` should be `toString()`. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `Example input of fUnit is "CS_25x2u" expected output of it after using unit is "u".`, in this case, is this `console.log("CS_25x2u".slice(-1))` the differentce from the result you expected?

Answer (score 1):

```
const regex = /[a-zA-Z]*$/;
console.log(regex.exec(sample));
```

Assuming fUnit variable contains your string

```
const unit = (x) => x.match(regex)[0];
console.log(unit(fUnit));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how would i apply it to the fUnit?

Comment: Because when i do fUnit.regex it doesnt work as well and gives me undefined

Comment: const unit = (x) => x.match(regex)[0];
console.log(unit(sample));

Comment: and how would i save the final value back in fUnit?

Comment: if you've defined fUnit using var or let instead of const. then you can simply do fUnit = unit(fUnit)

Comment: but im passing fUnit as a parameter so I dont think im supposed to redefine it right?

Comment: Im going to update my question and show the the function

Comment: what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case.

```js
function buildUnit(fUnit) {
  return fUnit.toString().match(/[A-z]*$/)[0];
}

console.log(buildUnit('CS_25x2u'));    // 'u'
console.log(buildUnit(''));            // ''
console.log(buildUnit(123));           // ''
console.log(buildUnit('aaa123'));      // ''
console.log(buildUnit('aaa 123 bbb')); // 'bbb'
```